# API Service not fetching/returning any data

Tags: angular, api, angular-material, angular-httpclient

`home.component.ts`:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { JonasUtilApiService } from '../service/jonas-util-api.service';
import { Spending } from './home.interface';

/**
 * @title Data table with sorting, pagination, and filtering.
 */

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
  ...
  ];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Spending>;

  spendings: Spending[] = [];
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;

  constructor(private jonasUtilApi: JonasUtilApiService) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.spendings);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.jonasUtilApi.getSpendings(100).subscribe((res) => {
      this.spendings = res;
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
}
```

`service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Spending } from '../home/home.interface';

const API_URL = 'https://apiaddressgooglecloud.a.run.app/';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class JonasUtilApiService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getSpendings(limit: number = 50) {
    console.log('call', limit, `${API_URL}spendings`);
    return this.httpClient.get<Spending[]>(`${API_URL}spendings`, {
      params: { limit: limit },
    });
  }

  storeDataFromList(body: any) {
    return this.httpClient.post(`${API_URL}callback/monthlyHours`, body);
  }
}
```

The URL is certainly working if I click on it, data is returned in browser. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I haven't coded in Angular in quite a bit of time, so a bit rusty, but double checked online and it seems to be the correct way.

Comment: What type of response are you expecting ?Json? Text?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the browser is logging the data you are not waiting for it in terms of the browser.

You should resolve your data as a promise, and await it in the component.

in the most simplistic terms you should subscribe to the returned data, you could assign it to a behavior subject or subject using rxjs.  this way you can subscribe to the fetched data anywhere in your app.

so as an example on your service:

```
private httpReturned = new BehaviorSubject<any>({} as any);
public httpReturned$ = this.httpReturned.asObservable();

this.httpClient.get<Spending[]>(`${API_URL}spendings`, {
      params: { limit: limit },
    }).subscribe(async (res)=>{
      const dataReturned = await Promise.resolve(res);
      this.httpReturned.next(dataReturned);;
    })
```

then on any component whatever you've called the service.

```
yourData:any;
constructor(private yourservice:YourService);

ngOnInit(){
this.yourservice.httpReturned$.subscribe(async (res_your_data)=>{
this.yourData = await res_your_data;
})
}
```

Comment: it would be wise to bind this to an interface or type for type security concerns.  but this is the general usage of a behavior subject and will allow you to access the data anywhere in your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but why do I need to subscribe and create a new Subject or BehaviorSubject if the underlying function already resolves to an Observable. That makes no immediate sense to me.

Comment: you are not able to store that data and reuse it, instead every time its a fetch.  this could prove costly in terms of taxonomy and invocation costs.  your data cannot be reused throughout your application, only once.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution and the problem was that I was not updating my datasource, adding this to the component solved it:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.jonasUtilApi.getSpendings(100).subscribe((res) => {
    this.spendings = res;
    this.dataSource.data = this.spendings;
  });
}
```